# Implementar soma numérica apenas com sucessor e antecessor

Tags: c

Considere um sistema numérico que não tenha a operação de adição
implementada e que você disponha somente dos operadores (funções)
sucessor e predecessor. Então, pede-se para escrever uma função
recursiva que calcule a soma de dois números x e y através desses dois
operadores: sucessor e predecessor.

Comment: E o que você quer exatamente? Uma explicação do que é sucessor e predecessor?

Comment: isso eu ja sei, mas nao sei como resolver o problema, nem consigo pensar numa forma

Answer (score 2):

Para simplificar a resposta, irei considerar apenas que as entradas serão números inteiros não negativos. É dado que existem dois operadores no sistema numérico utilizado onde representarei como `x+` o operador sucessor e `x-` o antecessor. Pede-se para implementar uma função recursiva que retorne a soma de dois números. A lógica a ser implementada é: incrementar um dos valores ao passo que o outro é decrementado, enquanto este (que está reduzindo) não chegue em zero; quando chegar, parar a recursão. Assim, em uma pseudo-linguagem que acabei de inventar, ficaria:

```
function sum(x: int, y: int): int
    if y = 0:
        return x
    return sum(x+, y-)
```

Para não quebrar a magia, implementei em Python apenas para mostrar que funciona:

```
sucessor = lambda x: x+1
antecessor = lambda x: x-1

def sum(x, y):
    if not y:
        return x
    return sum(sucessor(x), antecessor(y))

print(sum(3, 5))  # 8
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/WarmDetailedVisitor) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/lHno00) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/ad865d017448689baf2969b9630fccb8)</sup>

Quanto a implementação em C, acredito que com isso você já consiga elaborar algo por conta, mas, qualquer coisa, sinta-se a vontade para questionar.

Comment: agora sim, muito obrigado, ajudou muito!